# Uri for bitmap in subfolder (c# wpf)

Tags: c#, bitmap, uri

I have a wpf app where I'm using an image.  To reference the image I use:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/assemblyName;Component/myIcon.png");
BitmapImage(uri)
```

If I add the png directly under the csproj file (with its properties BuildAction=Resource) then it works fine.

But I want to move it to a subfolder under the csproj.  Another SO question asked about bitmaps\uri's ([857732](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857732/how-can-i-get-a-bitmapimage-from-a-resource)) and an answer linked to this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly).  So I tried :

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/assemblyName;Component/Icons/myIcon.png");
```

But that did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

If the image is in your solution (i.e., you are not referencing the image from another assembly), you should be able to use this syntax:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Icons/myIcon.png", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Or, you can use a relative Uri as follows:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/Icons/myIcon.png", UriKind.Relative);
```