# How to: Use images which are part of a dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, bitmap, uri

**How to: Use images which are part of a dll**

I created a dll which has a public method that uses images. These images are embedded. Now when I try using the assembly in my new project, everythings works fine except the images.

I tried to run the application without using an assembly (just a normal WPF application) and it worked. So it seems, that the application does not find the embedded images from the dll.

**The way I create the images used in my dll:**

```
public void CreateBitmapImage(string uri)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute);
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        image_msgIcon.Source = bitmapImage;
    }

    public void SetMsgImage(string msgImage)
    {
        if (msgImage == Error)
        {
            CreateBitmapImage("pack://application:,,,/CL.New;component/Images/CustomMessageBox/cross-circle.png");
        }
        else if (msgImage == Exclamation)
        {
            CreateBitmapImage("pack://application:,,,/CL.New;component/Images/CustomMessageBox/exclamation.png");
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

**Now I get this error message:**

```
Die Ressource "images/custommessagebox/cross-circle.png" kann nicht gefunden werden.
The resource "images/custommessagebox/cross-circle.png" cannot be found.
```

**I tried it this way:**

```
CreateBitmapImage("/CL.New;component/Images/CustomMessageBox/cross-circle.png");
```

...

```
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);
```

... this seems to work, but the image is not displayed (no error messages).

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857732/how-can-i-get-a-bitmapimage-from-a-resource and links from it.

Comment: The problem in this case is not equal to my problem - two very different things.

Comment: Have you declared your image as "Resource"?

Comment: Thanks, ptk93! That was the last thing missing. Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ptk93: Have you declared your image as "Resource"?

**--> Solution.**